# Riesz transform of fractional operators

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am interested in Riesz transforms linked to the fractional Laplacian and other fractional operators. I have been hunting down in the literature to find related results but I have not been able to find any.

Any related references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not think it is immediately clear what is the notion of a Riesz transform corresponding to a fractional operator. Do you mean something like $\partial_x L^{-1}$, where, say, $L = (-\Delta)^s$?

Comment: I am looking for Riesz transforms of the form $D L^{-1/2}$ with $L=(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}$ $\alpha \in (0,2)$ and $D$ some (fractional) derivative operator.

Comment: Then it looks like you are after fractional powers of the usual Riesz transforms, right? I do not think these have been studied much, but general theory of singular integrals should apply. (By the way, out of curiosity: what is your motivation to study these operators?)

Comment: Meyer's inequality with a stable reference measure

Comment: Some results on the Riesz transform for the fractional Laplacian with (a kind of) fractional derivative are contained in this paper by Junge, Mei and Parcet: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.2475.pdf (see 1.4.A). Is this something of the kind you were looking for?

Comment: thanks. I have been aware of this paper published in JEMS. I was wondering if generalizations of the fractional laplacian have been considered in the literature and if the continuity results with dimension free bound would have been obtained by transference method.

Answer (score 2):

You can find an elementary and very detailed approach to fractional operators and Riesz transforms in

http://www.pitt.edu/~hajlasz/Notatki/Harmonic%20Analysis4.pdf

See in particular the last section, pages 109-117. I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the reference and your answer. I am looking for something intrinsically fractional for the "first order" derivative operator used to define the Riesz transform.